# Discover a specific Bluetooth devices for devices those have an existing application

Tags: android

I'm building an application X, and this application needs to connect to other devices those have the same application (X) via Bluetooth, so I want to list the available devices, but I need to list just the devices those have the application X, is there any way to get a specific devices those installed the application X?

Comment: Can you not just store the users in a db (or more helpfully the active users) and then access those that are nearby? If you are trying to check other devices from afar, essentially hacking them) you may run into trouble.

Comment: Read about [NSD](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html) and see if that might be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: connecting app instances via Bluetooth will require implementation of both client and server sides, both using the same service record uuid.

Before connect you will need to perform a Bluetooth scan to find all BT available devices in your vicinity.

And in details:

**Perform Discovery**

```
// get adapter
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

// create discovery listener
discoveryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
              BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
          allDiscoveredDevices.add(device);
        }   
    };

// and register it 
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
return context.registerReceiver(discoveryReceiver, filter);  

// start discovert
boolean started = bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery(); //async call!
if (!started) {
   // log error
}
```

Once you know the BT devies in your area, attempt connect using your app's UUID:

**Client Connect**

```
BluetoothSocket sock = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_APP_UUID);
try {
      sock.connect(context);
      // if here: two peers of your app are now connected <--------------------
} catch (Exception e) {
     // no peer app found
}
```

And the BT server logic:

**Server Loop**

```
BluetoothServerSocket ssocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(name, MY_APP_UUID);

while (serverIsRunning) {
     try {
           clientSocket = btServerSocket.accept(); // returns a connected socket
     } catch (IOException e) {
           // log error
     }
}
```

It should be made clear that the above is *naive* coding. Real life BT connectivity is much more complex. It deals with edge conditions that may rely on each peer's OS version. It may require you to access hidden API e.g. via reflection.

[BTWiz](https://github.com/giladHaimov/BTWiz), an open source Android BT library developed by yours truly, handles much of this complexity 
for you and also exposes an async IO interface that makes BT communication significantly simpler.

Feel free to use it. But even if not - you might want to browse through its code and see how it deals 
with common BT problem relating to discovery & connection.