# Discovering Bluetooth Devices only for devices with a required application

Tags: android, security, network-programming, android-bluetooth

I'm working on an android app where one user can connect to another person who has the same application, via Bluetooth connection. This peer-peer connection, only should allow persons with the same application to be able to discover your device and connect to it. Is it possible to 'mask' your device and only allow a device that has the same application that is being used for communication to discover your device?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discover a specific Bluetooth devices for devices those have an existing application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499019/discover-a-specific-bluetooth-devices-for-devices-those-have-an-existing-applica)

Comment: I haven't received a response so I went on the android group. I tried to delete this but couldn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. As soon as you start advertising your device is visible to all bluetooth devices. You would need to implement an authentication after the connection was established and then drop the connection if a device cannot authenticate itself.